# Stop the modify time of a file from getting changed

Tags: unix, stat

There are three time values for a file:

1. **access** - when the file is read.
2. **modify** - when the file content is modified.
3. **change** - when the metadata of the file is changed.

We can see these time values on using `stat` command in Unix.
Is there any way to make the modify time constant and not let it change even if the file content is changed?

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 OS.

￼
@Abhash Upadhyaya
I tried this. But the modify time is changing each time I access the file. I want the time to be same even after it is accessed or its contents are changed.

```
ridhima@ridhima:~$ touch -d 20120101 goldenfile
ridhima@ridhima:~$ stat goldenfile 
  File: ‘goldenfile’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 5259884     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (618146911/ridhima)   Gid: (618136065/domain^users)
Access: 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0530
Modify: 2012-01-01 00:00:00.000000000 +0530
Change: 2015-11-24 12:01:34.838442527 +0530
 Birth: -
ridhima@ridhima:~$ 
ridhima@ridhima:~$ 
ridhima@ridhima:~$ 
ridhima@ridhima:~$ touch goldenfile 
ridhima@ridhima:~$ stat goldenfile 
  File: ‘goldenfile’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 5259884     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (618146911/ridhima)   Gid: (618136065/domain^users)
Access: 2015-11-24 12:01:44.378442982 +0530
Modify: 2015-11-24 12:01:44.378442982 +0530
Change: 2015-11-24 12:01:44.378442982 +0530
 Birth: -
ridhima@ridhima:~$ vi goldenfile 
ridhima@ridhima:~$ stat goldenfile 
  File: ‘goldenfile’
  Size: 5           Blocks: 8          IO Block: 4096   regular file
Device: 805h/2053d  Inode: 5259943     Links: 1
Access: (0644/-rw-r--r--)  Uid: (618146911/ridhima)   Gid: (618136065/domain^users)
Access: 2015-11-24 12:02:09.662444188 +0530
Modify: 2015-11-24 12:02:09.662444188 +0530
Change: 2015-11-24 12:02:09.666444188 +0530
 Birth: -
```

Comment: You can sometimes do it by mounting the file system with appropriate flags.  For example, if the file system is mounted read-only, no times will change.  There may also be more specialized options.  Whether you can do it for a single file depends on the file system.  There may be 'immutable' flags — which prevents the file changing and hence the modification time changing.  I'm not sure that there's a way to allow the file to be modified but prevent the modification time from being updated.  Someone else will have to tell you if there is — I'm going to make an informed guess that there isn't.

Comment: @Ridhima, Ubuntu, depending when/how you installed it, uses `relatime` or `noatime` mount options by default - this means that tracking of access times is basically disabled. You can change it by removing that option from `/etc/fstab` and rebooting. Or, for instance `sudo mount -o remount,atime /home` on the relevant filesystem.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the touch command.

For example purposes here's a goldenfile that was created with some arbitrary timestamp.

```
$ touch -d 20120101 goldenfile
$ ls -l goldenfile 
-rw-rw-r--. 1 user user 0 Jan  1  2012 goldenfile
```

You can use various switches for your purpose like

1. -a     change only the access time
2. -m     change only the modification time

For more information on touch command, do a `$ man touch` on terminal.

Comment: This sets the modification time on the file (thereby changing it, in general), whereas the question is asking how to prevent the modification time from being changed at all.